# How can I use SSL Connection by Android connect to MySQL?

Tags: java, android, mysql, ssl

I would like to use the SSL connection to MySQL datebase, but I don't understand how to use the below code under the SSL keystore connect to the database form Android device and I used the (non-SSL) connect to database is successful and without an error for collect data, please help, thanks!

```
KeyStore trustSt = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
InputStream trustStoreStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);
trustSt.load(trustStoreStream, "123456".toCharArray());
trustManagerFactory.init(trustSt);

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
InputStream keyStoreStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, "123456".toCharArray());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "123456".toCharArray());

sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);


Connection con;

try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/db?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&",db_user,db_password);

}catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    tv.setText(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: have you setup SSL on MySQL? For both standard and SSL traffic?

Comment: Yes, I tried on MySQL Workbench with three SSL (CA, CERT & Key) is workable.